# JPA @Version overflow

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

The JPA specification (2.1) says that:

> The following types are supported for version properties: int, Integer, short, Short, long,Long, Timestamp

What is the expected behavior after a `@Version` property overflows?

Comment: I guess this is an academical question, since even if you have 1 billion updates per day it would take about 25 million years to get an overflow with Long...

Comment: Note that the version property may be `short`, in which case it only takes 32k updates.

Comment: why not try it, see what datastore type a "short" will create, and then do an INSERT of the max of a short + 1 ... does the datastore throw an SQLException?

Comment: I would not recommend setting your @Version property yourself. Be prepared for some unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would expect it to work correctly. No error occurs on overflow and version++ != version. It will result in the risk of overwriting updates if you're using short and have 65536 transactions with updates on this entity before the first one finishes.

Edit: when you use @Version, then update queries will not look like this:

```
update person set surname = ? where id = ?
```

but like this:

```
update person set surname = ?, version_field = ? where id = ? and version_field = ?
```

now JDBC will return the update count upon completion. If no update has been made, then the JPA implementation will assume that no data with the specified id and version was found -> Exception.

Comment: Doesn't it matter that version>++version?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm EasterBunnyBugSmasher's answer on Hibernate 5. Defined a byte @Version field, once reached 128 went around to -127 and kept looping.

(I have no reputation to comment)

Comment: You don't need to confirm anyone's answer. If you had enough rep, you could upvote it. But what you posted (which isn't an answer) is just going to get downvoted and deleted, helping nobody. Also, not sure why you chose to do this on a question asked, and answered, three years ago.

Comment: His answer was started with "I would expect it to...", with +3 only, so I had to verify before using. Thought saving someone else the time. Of course if that is not welcomed, I won't do again.

Comment: Gabor - it's not a matter of not being welcomed. This is just how StackOverflow's guidelines are set up. Note that the answer was already accepted, validating it. And upvotes *are* appreciated, both by people asking questions, and by those who answer them. And it only takes a few rep points (15) to have that ability.